# UIBarbuttonItem has no title on ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I have an app, which I am migrating to iOS 7. 
However, the `UIBarbuttonItem`s have no title, but are working normally.
Here is my code :

```
UIBarButtonItem * uibbShare = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sharewhite.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(sharePressed:)] autorelease];
// uibbShare.width = 56.0;  // uncommenting this doesn't change anything
uibbShare.title = @"Share";
```

Then I add some of these to the toolbar with some flexible space items between.

```
...
 [items addObject:flex2];
 [items addObject:uibbShare];
...
```

`[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];`

On iOS 7 they have no title at all, on iOS6 all is working fine. Can't you create barbuttons like this in ios7 anymore ?

**Update** Same problem on Dev Forums :

[UIBarButtonItem can't have both title and image?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/872899#872899)

[What happened to the text under toolbar icons?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/867947#867947)

**Edit** : ( 7 vs 6 )

[image]

**Edit 2** : ( a picture from Reveal, it seems the text is gone, and the frame/bounds are 0. wtf )

[image]

Comment: I can see below on picture than isHidden is checked. Could be this the problem?

Comment: It may be, but it's an internal view, can't (and don't want to) access it... It's strange that i don't hide it anywhere, don't use the toolbar only in the code lines above in `viewDidLoad`. If I initialize it with title (no image), it shows the text ... I'd want both...

Comment: Could you access programmatically to this property and modify it? Somthing like UIButtonLabel.hidden = NO.

Comment: I've modified my previous answer with little code to try.

Comment: As I said, it's an internal view, AppStore  probably won't approve it if I modify it manually. Anyway, the frame and bounds are both null, even if I set the hidden = NO, it won't do anything. Can't find anything why this isn't working anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Eventually ended up creating customviews for the UIBarButtonItems. It isn't nice, but it works momentarily. I just pass the old UIBarButtonItems to this function which returns a new one.

Note: I just shift up the button's image if there is a title and add a simple label below, not actually messing with titleEdgeInsets and centering . Also, I'm setting the width to the default 56.

```
-(UIBarButtonItem *)convertToButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)original
{
    if ( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0"))
        return  original;

    CGFloat textFieldHeight = 13.f;
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 56, self.toolbar.frame.size.height);
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [button setImage:original.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:original.target action:original.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = original.tag;

    UIView * wr = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 56, self.toolbar.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
    [wr addSubview:button];
    wr.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (original.title != nil)
    {
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7, 0, 0, 0);
        UILabel * l = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.toolbar.frame.size.height - textFieldHeight, 56, textFieldHeight)] autorelease];
        l.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.f];
        l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        l.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        l.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        l.text = original.title;
        [wr addSubview:l];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem * theNew = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:wr] autorelease];
    theNew.tag = original.tag;
    theNew.width = 56;
    return theNew;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont 
    fontWithName:@"YOURFONT" size:14], NSFontAttributeName, 
    [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
```

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
The key is to use NSFontAttributeName and so forth. I assume they are moving over to using the NS variety for 64-bit compatibility. The above code worked on my iOS7 device

Comment: Well, this changes the navigation bar, not the `UIToolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the appearance of the button:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor textColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIFont yourFont and yourSizeSont], UITextAttributeFont, [UIColor shadowColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Following to my last comment I've thought in something like this:

```
NSArray *views = [_UIToolbarNavigationButton subviews];

for (UIView *view in views) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButtonLabel class]])
    {
        view.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

I don' know if it colud be useful.

Comment: This changes the `UIBarButtonItems` on the navigationbar, but on my toolbar the items still are the same, with no title :(